# Issue: tf.function raising a warning and failing with tf.stack

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am having problems with `tf.function` in tensorflow. It seems to fail to convert functions containing the instruction `tf.stack()`.

Here a simple code I wrote to highlight the issue:

```
import tensorflow as tf
c = tf.Variable([[1., 5.], [2., 4.]])
@tf.function
def toy_fct(x):
    y = tf.stack([x[0,:], x[1,:]], axis=0)
    return y
toy_fct(c)
```

The messages I get are the following:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:AutoGraph could not transform <function toy_fct at 0x000001DC9A13A670> and will run it as-is.
Please report this to the TensorFlow team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output.
Cause: module 'gast' has no attribute 'Index'
To silence this warning, decorate the function with @tf.autograph.experimental.do_not_convert
WARNING: AutoGraph could not transform <function toy_fct at 0x000001DC9A13A670> and will run it as-is.
Please report this to the TensorFlow team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output.
Cause: module 'gast' has no attribute 'Index'
To silence this warning, decorate the function with @tf.autograph.experimental.do_not_convert

<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[1., 5.],
       [2., 4.]], dtype=float32)>
```

Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: Similar issue with `gast` is reported here, https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/44146. Try to check with nightly. It shown in the `Done` card for tensorflow `2.5`, https://github.com/orgs/tensorflow/projects/11#card-56720964.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested your code in `tf 2.0` to `tf 2.4` without any issue. But it appears when I used `gast==0.4.0`. Try this

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install gast==0.2.2
```

---

FYI, it runs fine with `gast==0.4.0` with latest `tf 2.5.0-rc0`.

Comment: For some reason, conda doesn't allow me to downgrade gast because of incompatibilities. I will try to mess around to find a combination that solves the issue. Thanks!